# how to select an item in selectlist in view model MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, selectlist

I am new in mvc 4 but getting progress. I'm getting crazy with something which how i can select an item in select list in view model.
here is my controller code;

```
ViewBag.DepartmanListesi = new SelectList(VeriTabani.UnvanDepartmanlaris, "UDepId", "Departman");
```

and in my view model I am listing a diffirent database but in this list one field includes an id of the `UnvanDepartmanlaris`.instead of showing the id, I want to show name of the id. but what I have tried is not worked. can you please help me.

I searched many things but most of them was about how to set dropdownlist. I couldnt find any answer of my question.

Thank you in advance. I will be waiting for any response

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: i've checked this information but i am not interested in dropdownlist. i want to make something like query with selectlist in view model.

Comment: That's a `SelectList` constructor. What does `DropDownList` have to do with anything? Are you asking how to set the selected item *after* the list is created?

Comment: I guess  i may explain wrongly my issue about what i want to do. In the fact what i want to do is, the view model has listing a database and one of the field includes an id of the diffirent database. instead of showing the id, i want to show the name of the field which belongs another database. I thougth to do this i need a selectlist. so here is what i am tring to do. so please tell me what is the way i should fallow in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using following approach. Hope it helps:

Create helper class (I'm having here all my selectlists)

```
Public static class Helper
{
public static List<SelectListItem> GetList()
        {
            var result = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var ctx = new YourContext();

            var items = from n in ctx.Clients
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = n.Client.Name,
                            Value = n.ClientID.ToString()
                        };

            foreach (var item in items)
                result.Add(item);
            return result;
        }
}
```

Than in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("GetClients", Helper.GetList())
```

Works for me.

Comment: Thank you, i will try and make a feedback

Comment: this is so helpfull and worked for me. thank you so much my firend and  appreciate so much.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

**Controller**

```
 public List<CustomerModel> GetCustomerName()
        {
            // Customer DropDown
            using (dataDataContext _context = new dataDataContext())
            {
                return (from c in _context.Customers
                        select new CustomerModel
                        {
                            CustomerId = c.CID,
                            customerName = c.CustomerName
                        }).ToList<CustomerModel>();
            }
        }

  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CustomerInfo()
        {

            var List = GetCustomerName();
            ViewBag.CustomerNameID = new SelectList(List, "CustomerId", "customerName");
            return View();
        }
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("CustomerId", (SelectList)ViewBag.CustomerNameID, "--Select--")
```

**Model**

```
public class CustomerModel
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public string customerName { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> customerNameList { get; set; }
}
```